# Loop-execution of a set of Python scripts with arguments from the main script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a child python script that takes an argument and takes approx. 8 minutes to run.

```
e.g. python.exe child.py "2018-01-01"
```

I need to execute this script many times from a main script. I am considering using `subprocess.Popen`.

```
import os, sys, time, subprocess
for date in ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", ..., "2018-12-31"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', "child.py", date])
    time.sleep(600)
```

As the `Popen` function does not know when the child script finishes executing, it just keeps triggering the child script with the argument. So I had to need to set 600 seconds of sleep time (longer than the approximate run time for the child script) so the subsequent run safely starts after the previous run finishes.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to dealing this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the scripts need to run synchronously, consider using `subprocess`. More specifilcally, the `run` function (>=3.5). Or even the `call` function (<3.5), which is the same as `run` but it only returns the code from the script. Both block the calling script until return.

Your code would become:

```py
import shlex
import subprocess

for date in ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", ..., "2018-12-31"]:
    command = 'python.exe child.py %s' % date
    args = shlex.split(command)
    res = subprocess.run(args)
```

If you need it to run asyncrhonously, consider using `xargs`. If you **really** need to do it in python, use `multiprocessing` our `multiprocessing.dummy` to do it.

Comment: Thanks! In Python 2.7 I had to use `command = 'python.exe child.py {}'.format(date)` to get it work.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. F-strings are >3.6. My bad

Answer (score 0):

how about this, call the wait() so the current subprocess is done before launching another one.

```
for date in ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", ..., "2018-12-31"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', "child.py", date])
    p.wait()
    rc = p.returncode
    print(rc)
```